# Excluding executable file in Tar

Tags: bash, makefile, backup

I'm doing a backup of my program, and i want to exclude the executable file from the bin directory.

I'm doing this but it's not working properly:

```
newFiles=( "bin" "include" "obj" "src" "makefile" "create_backup.sh")

tar -pczf ../backup_`date +%Y-%m-%d_%I-%M-%S`.tar.gz ${newFiles[*]} --exclude='./bin/*'
```

This way the executable is still in the bin folder after the backup is done.

How can i do it properly?

Comment: Why do you include  `"bin"` as the first item in your `newfiles` variable if you want to exclude it? What do you mean by *"the executable is still in the bin folder afterwards"* - of course it is - did you expect `tar` to delete files in your filesystem?

Comment: @MarkSetchell i want to delete the executable inside bin

Comment: This doesn't make sense! You explicitly include `bin` in the first line, yet you also try to exclude it in the second. Which is it to be?

Comment: i want to keep the bin directory, but exclude the executable inside it @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `--exclude` in front of `newFiles` in the order on the commandline, and also explcitly naming the unwanted file like this:

```
tar -pczf ../backup_`date +%Y-%m-%d_%I-%M-%S`.tar.gz --exclude='./bin/UnwantedExecutableName' ${newFiles[*]}
```